# defining 2 seperate objects but calling a function on one still changes the other

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I was coding in javascript (nodeJS) when i needed some what to implement a flag for if a certain function can run on an event or not. I thought a smart way to do this would be to create a separate file where i keep track of all my flags (if there is a better way feel free to tell me). I created a flag object like this:

```
let flag1 = {
    value: false,
    set: (value) => {
        this.value = value
    },
    get: () => {
        return this.value
    }
}

module.exports = {flag1}
```

This worked great until I added a second flag. I was lazy and just copy pasted the statement to create the first flag, I changed the name and added it to the exports.

```
let flag1 = {
    value: false,
    set: (value) => {
        this.value = value
    },
    get: () => {
        return this.value
    }
}

let flag2 = {
    value: false,
    set: (value) => {
        this.value = value
    },
    get: () => {
        return this.value
    }
}

module.exports = {flag1, flag2}
```

But to my big suprise when I called

```
flag1.set(true)
console.log(flag1.get())
console.log(flag2.get())
```

the response was

```
true
true
```

How is this possible?
What I find even more confusing is that when I just now created a function that creates flag variables, the objects behave completely as expected ... (code below works)

```
function createFlag() {
    this.value = false
    this.set = (value) => {
        this.value = value
    }
    this.get = () => {
        return this.value
    }
}

const flag1 = new createFlag()
const flag2 = new createFlag()
```

What is the difference between the 2 because I really can't tell.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your first piece of code, `this` always refers to the same global object, called `global` in Node.js and `window` in a browser. Within the function `createFlag`, it refers to the instance created by `new createFlag()`. The latter is the behavior you expect.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen - FWIW, in modern environments that object is accessible via `globalThis` in browsers and Node.js (and Deno, etc.).

Comment: Side note: Functions like `createFlag` that you expect to use with `new` (*constructor* functions) should, by standard convention, start with a capital letter (so: `CreateFlag` or more likely just `Flag`). And to ensure they have to be called via `new`, you might consider using [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). The constructor functions created via `class` can't be called without `new` (or similar).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had no idea it was because of "this" keyword. @T.J.Crowder thanks for the suggestions, I implemented them immediately.